# How can I transform this table, by making values of a column as new columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, with columns

- contractID
- paymentID
- paymentStatus (values are "Received", "Approved", "Processed", and more)
- statusDate

It records the history of change of status of each (contract, payment).

I was wondering how to get a table:

- contractID
- paymentID
- statusDateOfReceived
- statusDateOfApproved
- statusDateOfProcessed

in SQL Server.

A (contract, payment) may go through changes of statuses: Received -> Approved -> Processed. But the data is not complete, so some (contract, payment) may miss some status, in which case, the statusDate... will be NULL.

Comment: Your question is ambigious at best.   Sample data and desired results would be more helpful.   For example are you looking for a conditional aggregation or just the columns extended?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
SELECT contractID, paymentID
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN paymentStatus = 'Received' THEN StatusDate END) As ReceivedDate
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN paymentStatus = 'Approved' THEN StatusDate END) As ApprovedDate
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN paymentStatus = 'Processed' THEN StatusDate END) As ProcessedDate
FROM [MyTable]
GROUP BY contractID, paymentID
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering what `MAX` is used here for?

Comment: @Tim because of the `GROUP BY`. You are required to have an aggregate function of some kind, to decide which of the potentially several values in the group to show.

Comment: Thanks. Does MAX apply to all data types? What if a field is varchar etc?

Comment: I sure hope you're not using varchar for a column like `StatusDate` to store Date information. That would be dumb. Schemas like that need to _fixed_, because they really are considered **broken**. But yes, MAX() does work for varchar data; it just sorts it like a string, no matter what. If you have values `2022-6-22` and `2022-12-25`, then the MAX() would be `2022-6-22` because it looks like the larger value when seen as a string.

Comment: Thanks again. Can the answer be rephrased in terms of PIVOT?

Comment: Why? It's more code and and conditional aggregation is likely to be more efficient here.