# When shall I use which, PIVOT in FROM or GROUP BY outside FROM clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

From SQL Server's T-SQL document, the syntax for a PIVOT clause in a FROM clause is:

```
[ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]  

<table_source> ::=   
{  
    table_or_view_name [ FOR SYSTEM_TIME <system_time> ] [ AS ] table_alias ]   
        [ <tablesample_clause> ]   
        [ WITH ( < table_hint > [ [ , ]...n ] ) ]   
    | rowset_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]   
        [ ( bulk_column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]   
    | user_defined_function [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
    | OPENXML <openxml_clause>   
    | derived_table [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ ( column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]   
    | <joined_table>   
    | <pivoted_table>   
    | <unpivoted_table>  
    | @variable [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
    | @variable.function_call ( expression [ ,...n ] )   
        [ [ AS ] table_alias ] [ (column_alias [ ,...n ] ) ]     
}  

<pivoted_table> ::=  
    table_source PIVOT <pivot_clause> [ [ AS ] table_alias ]  
  
<pivot_clause> ::=  
        ( aggregate_function ( value_column [ [ , ]...n ])   
        FOR pivot_column   
        IN ( <column_list> )   
    )
```

Is

```
SELECT *
FROM table_source PIVOT ( aggregate_function ( value_column)   
        FOR pivot_column   
        IN ( value1, value2 )   
    )
```

equivalent to

```
SELECT pivot_column, aggregate_function(value_column)
FROM table_source 
WHERE pivot_column = value1 OR pivot_column = value2
GROUP BY pivot_column
```

?

Are both PIVOT and GROUP BY  used for doing the same thing: group records by some columns (and then aggregate over some other columns)?

When shall PIVOT be used, and when shall GROUP BY be used?

Answer (score 1):

No. It is effectively conditional aggregation, and is equivalent to

```sql
SELECT
  other_columns_here,
  value1 = aggregate_function(CASE WHEN pivot_column = value1 THEN value_column END),
  value2 = aggregate_function(CASE WHEN pivot_column = value2 THEN value_column END)
FROM table_source 
GROUP BY
  other_columns_here;
```

You can see that this is what it's transformed into if you examine the query plan.

As it happens, most good SQL writers do not use `PIVOT` except for very large value lists, because it's pretty inflexible. It's normally better to just use `GROUP BY`, although it can be more verbose.

Comment: Thanks. What is it inflexible about PIVOT?

Comment: What is it wrong about my "equivalence"?

Comment: I was wondering if this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72707118/156458 can be rephrased in terms of PIVOT?

Comment: It is very limited in terms of what aggregates are allowed, and how many columns (only one pivoted column), and that all non-pivoted columns are grouped. What's wrong: it's just wrong. Compare the two and you'll see the difference. Yes, it could be converted `SELECT * FROM MyTable PIVOT ( MAX(StatusDate) FOR paymentStatus IN (Received, Approved, Processed) ) pvt` If there are more columns that you want to ignore then you might need to use a derived table also.